# Dell poweredge r620 Memory Population

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

In my Dell poweredge R620 server i install 8GB 12 Memory stick in slot B1-B12,but some memory stick not showing(B5,B6,B9,B10),server usable memory is 64gb now.Plz suggest me RAM accurate population.

Edit:All RAM are same configuratin(8gb,2Rx4,DDR3 PC3L-10600R 1333MHZ) OS-Windows Server 2012 Standard

Comment: Have you checked the Dell documentation to make sure the memory and memory configuration are supported?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of your server's cores follow the table in this [link](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/490091/Dell-Poweredge-R620.html?page=44)
For two processors (probably your case) you should place

- 6 DIMMs in A1 to A6
- 6 DIMMs in B1 to B6